# How to add multiple Fields in the Bucket sort Elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Below is the query. Inside this query, I need to add one more field which is `category.keyword`.
I am finding it difficult to add an additional field. Please modify my query and add the category keyword field also inside the Query.

My requirement is to show the list of questions and list of categories with the count.

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "genres": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "bucket_truncate": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Index Mapping details

```
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "answer": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "category": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "question": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "relavence_score": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "source": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
}
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple aggregations at the same level, in your case `bucket_truncate` and `categories`:

```json
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "questions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "question.keyword",
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "categories": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "category.keyword",
            "order": {
              "_count": "desc"
            }
          }
        },
        "bucket_truncate": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "from": 0,
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ Evaldas Buinauskas, Thanks a lot for your quick response. Your query is giving me the output question separately and category separately. Actually My requirement I need to show the Question and category together..

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by saying _together_? @Prabhudas8703

Comment: It means Along with questions we need to show the category also.For Example: **"key" : "Is jumper good?",
          "doc_count" : 23,
          "genres" : {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
            "buckets" : [
              {
                "key" : "common questions ",
                "doc_count" : 23
              }
            ]
          }
        }**

Comment: @Prabhudas8703 how about now?